# Como cambio un timestamp de 13 digitos a una fecha legible

Tags: python

He intentado varios métodos, pero en todos me da una fecha errónea *2034* en el año. Este *timestamp* es de la API de `fxcm` *(openTime, closeTime)*.

```
from datetime import date
 
Date = date.fromtimestamp(2032021161141//1000)
 
print(Date)
```

```
timestamp=2032021175301
pd.to_datetime(timestamp//1000)
```

Y otros métodos más y todos no me dan la fecha, la cual tiene que ser 2021-02-03 y la hora:

Estos son algunos *timestamp*

```
2032021092755       
2032021093155   
2032021091230       
2032021092336   
2032021090210       
2032021090731   
2032021082143       
2032021090047   
2032021081129       
2032021081851
```

Answer (score 5):

Ni es un *"timespam"* (*segundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970*), ni tiene 13 dígitos. Se trata de una cadena que concatena la fecha y la hora, en total 14 dígitos.

Por ejemplo, el *open_time* `"02032021175301"` sería:

|  | valor | formato |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mes | 02 | %m |
| día | 03 | %d |
| año | 2021 | %Y |
| hora | 17 | %H |
| minutos | 53 | %M |
| segundos | 01 | %S |

La forma correcta de obtener el tiempo es usando `datetime.strptime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

open_time = "02032021175301"
fecha = datetime.strptime(open_time, "%m%d%Y%H%M%S")

print(fecha.strftime("%c"))

'Wed Feb  3 17:53:01 2021'
```

Los formatos que se usan con fechas y tiempos están en la documenación de [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: Muchas gracias!! no me hubiese dado cuenta nunca

Comment: Buena respuesta. A mí cada vez me gusta [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io), con el que haría `arrow.get('02032021161141', 'DDMMYYYYHHmmss')`.

Comment: Desconocía Arrow. Impresionante la flexibilidad que tiene para configurar _locales_. Muchas gracias.